# Subbing Duplicate username with a number at the end

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, scripting

Hello currently working on a school project for my Unix class.

Creating a user menu to add/create username using the first name + last name to create username(first initial+first four of last)

**Ex. John Smith = JSMIT**

now I can add usernames, but if someone was to enter the same or similar username, I need to be able to substitute it with a number at the end.

**Ex. James Smith = JSMIT1**

so far this is what I have, I know I need to use the ***substr function in awk***, but I'm not sure how exactly.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

```
   looptest=y
while [ "$looptest" = y ]
do
        echo -n "Enter Name: "; read name
        echo -n "Enter Last Name "; read last
        echo -n "Continue(y)es or (n)o "; read looptest
        user="${name:0:1}""${last:0:4}"
        echo "$name:$last:$user" >> userData
        done
```

Comment: If your bash version support it (bash 4.0), declare an associative array in which the keys are `$user` values and increment the value each time. Then concatenate *value-1* to your string except when the value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

this `awk` will return the suffix you need

```
awk -v name="JSMIT" '$0~name{sub(name,""); max=(max<$1+0)?$1+0:max}
                     END    {print max?max+1:""}' userData
```

so, if the name is missing (i.e. a new name) the suffix will be null, if exists it will return `max+1`.  You can incorporate this into your existing script.